# Read images from storage Android 11 without using "Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, storage, android-11

I'm developing an app, where I need to upload a picture from gallery to server. Everything works fine with Android 10. But now I'm using android 11 and I know that in Android 11 II tried using "Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION" but if I use this then I can't publish my app to playstore. If anyone knows an alternative, it would be a great help.

Comment: "I need to upload a picture from gallery to server" -- get a `Uri` to the picture, then use the code from [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html) or [here](https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/) to be able to upload the image using OkHttp and/or Retrofit.

Comment: The only problem I'm facing is " how to get that Uri to the picture"

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` (or `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`) to allow the user to choose a picture.